# PDF to word conversion software?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, format-conversion

Is there any free software available on Ubuntu that can convert a pdf file to a .doc file?

Comment: I think the current accepted answer is not the right one because it does not work. Abiword works!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`openoffice` (or alternatively the `libreoffice` fork) both have pdf import plugins and .doc export functionality... though both aspects suffer from conversion issues AFAIK. 
By this I mean that the conversion fidelity isn't always 100%.

**Abiword** also works in a similar way, if OpenOffice doesn't work on your system.

Comment: `libreoffice --invisible --convert-to docx:"MS Word 2007 XML" file.pdf` When I convert pdf to docx/doc it says "convert /home/file.pdf -> /home/file.docx using filter : MS Word 2007 XML,
Error: Please verify input parameters... (SfxBaseModel::impl_store <file:///home/file.docx> failed: 0xc10)"

Comment: @mohit Your proposal does not work in Debian 8.5.

Answer (score 53):

Download `Abiword` from `Ubuntu Software Center` or you can install it by typing following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install abiword
```

Then perform the conversion:

```
abiword --to=doc example.pdf
```

Comment: I up voted this solution, but I must inform people that as of 2018-10-25, the output is far from being perfect.  The formatting is not respected at all.

Comment: It's not Ubuntu software, but this works: https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/online/pdf-to-word.html

Answer (score 17):

I've had great success with [PDF to Word online](http://www.pdftoword.com/Default.aspx). This is not a desktop application, but a service, that works better than other things I've used.

Comment: thank you :) ive come across this before.but i was looking for a desktop software.this is not very accurate.

Comment: Please also make sure to check out the [privacy policy of this service](http://www.pdftoword.com/privacy.aspx) before uploading any personal documents.

Comment: @neo did you happen to find a more accurate service/tool?

Comment: I tried it on 2018-10-25. The formatting is not perfect; bullets were lost, indentation was wrong (probably because of the bullets gone). Still, worth a try. Maybe with a simpler PDF file, it would come out better.

However, I found this online service that did a very good job with very few formatting errors:  https://pdf2docx.com/

Comment: I just downloaded the AbiWord for my windows machine. It is similar to MSWord. Now can anyone please tell me how can I convert PDF to DOC using this?

Answer (score 11):

Install AbiWord from Ubuntu Software Center

Open Pdf Files with it.

Use Save As.. to save pdf in Word Doc format.

Its this easy :)

Comment: Abiword terminal tool is also great http://askubuntu.com/a/278759/25388

Answer (score 9):

I prefer converting **PDF** files first to **HTML** using **pdftohtml** included in the **poppler-utils** package, for example by means of a file manager context menu script merely consisting of this command:

```
pdftohtml -noframes -q -p -c "$1" "${1%\.pdf}-img.html"
```

Then I open the resulting **HTML** file in **LibreOffice Writer**, and (after a little editing) **Save As** any other document format I like.

*Note: Adding **-i** parameter to the command above produces HTML file without images.*

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Please try it with several different PDF files before  passing such a verdict ;-) Probably the PDF file you tried doesn't actually include any text other than images, in which case only some OCR recognition software would be helpful.

Comment: It worked for me. Abiword returned me a failed doc. Convert it to html and then to word will work on any case. If pdf is an image, of course only an OCR is required :/