# How to download a particular version of libreoffice using sudo cmd?

Tags: apt, software-installation, sudo, libreoffice

I am new to ubuntu OS. The thing is, I need to download the LibreOffice version 6.0.1 in my ubuntu OS. I tried the following command .

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice=6.3.0
```

it is showing Version '6.3.0' for 'LibreOffice' was not found. I don't want to download the package file and install it separately. All I need is a command by which I can download a particular version of a package in my os. Please help me with this.

Comment: 6.0.1 is no longer available in the Ubuntu repositories - it's much too old. Consider migrating to a supported release: 6.0.3 is in Ubuntu 18.04, and it's supported for three more years. You can download 6.0.1 from Launchpad.net,  but that is not recommended for a beginner -- wrong-version packages invite all kinds of advanced problems.

Comment: @user535733: OK Then let's consider 6.3.0 . Still i can't donwload that even

Comment: Then you are likely not running Ubuntu 18.04. Why the specific requirement?

Comment: I am running ubuntu 20.04. The specific requirement is like I just need LibreOffice to convert some pdf files into docs. using the command-line interface. To do that I don't need such a big package. So it will be better to use a light package. So I thought of using some previous versions. Then While trying to install older package I cant download the particular version. As I told u before I am completely new to ubuntu. So I don't know why I can't download it. That's y finally landed here.

Comment: Ah, a classic [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). See: [PDF to word conversion software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37548/pdf-to-word-conversion-software)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apt-cache policy` to see which versions of a package are available for install:

```
djrscally@valhalla:~$ apt-cache policy libreoffice
libreoffice:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Version table:
     1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
```

In other words, 6.4.2 is the lowest version of LibreOffice available in the focal sources. If you check the Ubuntu packages list, you'll see earlier versions in the sources for earlier versions of ubuntu, but it doesn't seem like a very good idea to install those.

The reason being; developers don't like distributing out-of-date software, so it's quite rare that you'll find old versions continuing to be distributed when much newer versions are available.

If you absolutely, desperately need to get version 6.3; [there's a PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Elibreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/libreoffice-6-3) for it for some reason. You can add it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-6-3
sudo apt-get update
```

At which point `apt-cache policy libreoffice` should tell you the 6.3 version is available, and `sudo apt-get install libreoffice=6.3.0` ought to work.